# How to remove the ";" separation in the csv File exported through React-Data-Table-Extension Component?

Tags: reactjs, datatables, export-to-csv, react-data-table-component

I'm using React Data Table and React Data Table Extension Components to display my data. The problem being faced is that the csv file exported through React-Data-Table-Extension Component is hardcoded in it's module to use ";" instead of "," in a csv file export.

Is there any way that I  can update my front-end React jsx code to fix the issue without updating much of the code block?
[image: Current Output of CSV file containing semicolon separation]

[image: Overall display of my data table by using below code.]

My Code sample is as under:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AppLayout from "../../components/layouts/AppLayout";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { ROUTES } from "../../utils/Constants";
import { ScrollToTopOnMount } from "../../utils/CommonFunctions";
import AdminTabs from "../../components/AdminTabs";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import {
  searchFunctionality,
  tableCustomStyles,
} from "../../utils/CommonFunctions";
import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions";
import "react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css";

export default function DepartmentMembers() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [filteredValue, setFilteredValue] = useState("");
  const [finalFilteredValue, setFinalFilteredValue] = useState("");
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  let pastScreenData = location?.state?.user?.users;
  pastScreenData.forEach((department, index) => {
    department.serial = index + 1;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const sortedData = pastScreenData.sort((a, b) =>
      a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)
    );
    const updatedData = sortedData.map((item, index) => ({
      ...item,
      serial: index + 1,
    }));

    const filteredData = searchFunctionality(
      updatedData,
      dataTableColumns,
      finalFilteredValue
    );
    setFilteredData(filteredData);
  }, [pastScreenData, finalFilteredValue]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleViewDepartments = () => {
    navigate(ROUTES.departments);
  };

  const dataTableColumns = [
    {
      name: "#",
      selector: "serial",
      cell: (row, index) => <div>{index + 1}</div>,
      sortable: false,
      width: "50px",
    },
    {
      name: "Last Name",
      selector: "lastName",
      id: "lastName",
      sortable: true,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "First Name",
      selector: "firstName",
      sortable: true,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Status",
      selector: "userStatus",
      wrap: true,
    },
  ];

  const tableData = {
    columns: dataTableColumns,
    data: filteredData,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AppLayout>
        <ScrollToTopOnMount />
        <AdminTabs />
        <form>
          <div className='tab-content bg-white border border-top-0 p-3'>
            <div>
              <button
                type='button'
                className='btn btn-secondary'
                onClick={handleViewDepartments}
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className='d-flex'>
              <h3 className='h3 mt-4'>
                Member(s) of {location?.state?.user?.name}:
              </h3>
            </div>

            <div>
              {!location?.state?.user?.users ? (
                <div className='d-flex justify-content-center p-3'>
                  Loading...
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div
                  className='d-flex align-intems-center flex-wrap col-md-6 col-lg-12'
                  style={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}
                >
                  <div
                    className='input-group ms-auto'
                    style={{ width: "auto", display: "inline-flex" }}
                  >
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      className='form-control'
                      placeholder='Search Members'
                      value={filteredValue}
                      aria-describedby='button-addon2'
                      onChange={(event) => setFilteredValue(event.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button
                      className='btn btn-outline-primary'
                      type='button'
                      id='button-addon2'
                      onClick={() => setFinalFilteredValue(filteredValue)}
                    >
                      Go
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type='button'
                      className='btn btn-outline-primary'
                      aria-label='Clear'
                      onClick={() => {
                        setFilteredValue("");
                        setFinalFilteredValue("");
                      }}
                    >
                      Clear
                    </button>
                  </div>

                  <DataTableExtensions {...tableData} filter={false}>
                    <DataTable
                      columns={dataTableColumns}
                      data={filteredData}
                      keyField={(row, index) => index.troString()}
                      noHeader
                      defaultSortFieldId={"lastName"}
                      defaultSortAsc={true}
                      customStyles={tableCustomStyles}
                      pagination
                      highlightOnHover
                    />
                  </DataTableExtensions>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div>
              <button
                type='button'
                className='btn btn-secondary'
                onClick={handleViewDepartments}
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </AppLayout>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code on the `react-data-table-component-extensions` project, it looks like it is hard-coded to a semi-colon.

https://github.com/barisates/react-data-table-component-extensions/blob/master/src/utilities.js

```
const concat = {
  csv: row => {
    const items = [];

    row.forEach(item => {
      if (typeof item === 'object' && item !== null) {
        items.push(Object.keys(item).map(key => `${key}: ${item[key]}`).join(';'));
      } else {
        items.push(item);
      }
    });

    return items.join(';');
  },
```

At a quick glance, I didn't see any way to override that export functionality either.

So, it appears that, at least out-of-the-box, you can't change that. You could either request that option be added, or make the change yourself and submit a PR.

Your other option would be to write your own component.

Comment: Thanks. I'm planning to don't use the export function of data table extension for now as the deadline for project is near. So currently going with the csv export option being provided by react data table component. It gives comma separated values